# Writing to a .txt file at a certain point

Tags: c#

What i am trying to do here is write to a .txt file a certain string the user has selected, but only at a certain part of the .txt file, for example:

A text file will contain:

```
#name|user_login
USERNAME
#password|pass_recovery|user_pass
PASSWORD
...
...
...
```

If i type in a `TextBox` the word `new_user` (for example) in the `combobox` drop down i'll select `USERNAME` i'm trying to find this line in the .txt file then append it like:

```
#name|user_login|new_user
USERNAME
#password|pass_recovery|user_pass
PASSWORD
...
...
...
```

The same would go for any of the lines in capital letters, my function so far is:

```
        public void WriteToAIFile(string findThis, string writeThis)
        {
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\rj-ai-fields.txt");
            foreach (string eachLine in fileContent) {
                if (findThis == eachLine) {
                    // we have found the macro we want, go back up 1 line and append: "|" + writeThis to the end of the line ...

                    //var writeContent = File.WriteAllText(@"LogicFiles\rj-ai-fields.txt");
                }
            }
        }
```

Is pretty basic, what i'm thinking is to loop each line until `findThis == eachLine` (which is the capital letter value) then append the `writeThis` to the end of that line, but i would need to go back up 1 line before appending, is there a bewtter way to achieve this at all? is a `foreach` loop needed at all i'm thinking? thank you for any help, it's appreciated.

Comment: If you can store a unique symbol (e.g. "<*username*>") where you want to insert your username you can avoid a foreach, and instead use a normal string lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this is to use a `for` loop to index over the array of strings, rather than`foreach`.

Then you can write a loop that starts at 1 instead of 0 and "lags" by one element, allowing you to append the text to the previous line more easily.

You would then have to write the last line of the file as an extra step after the loop terminates.

Something like this:

```
public void WriteToAIFile(string findThis, string writeThis)
{
    var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\rj-ai-fields.txt");

    using (var output = File.CreateText("My filename"))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < fileContent.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (fileContent[i] == findThis)
                output.WriteLine(fileContent[i-1] + "|" + writeThis);
            else
                output.WriteLine(fileContent[i-1]);
        }

        output.WriteLine(fileContent[fileContent.Length-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys, that is a much better approach Matthew, the ```for``` loop was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a line after a specific one, you should use a backwards for loop and a `List::Insert` method. See [List.Insert(Int32, T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert)